# Proof that $L =$ {$a^p : \text{p is prime} $} is not regular

Tags: prime-numbers, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I know that this question has **already** been  answered but the proofs provided do not seem intuitive to me and I propose one using Wilson's theorem.

Say $L$ is regular and its pumping length is $p \geq 1$.

Choose $q$ to be the **first prime** after $p$ and w = $a^q$ can be rewritten as:

$$a^la^wa^{q-w-l}$$

According to the Pumping Lemma:  $$ \ a^la^{wi}a^{q-w-l} = a^{q+w(i-1)} \ \in L \ \forall \ i \geq0 $$

Choosing $i$ to be $(q-1)! +2$ then $a^{q+w[(q-1)! + 1]}$ should be in $L$.

However we know that:

1. $q$ divides $q$
2. $q$ divides $(q-1)! + 1$ using Wilson's theorem
3. $q$ divides $w[(q-1)! + 1]$ due to $2.$
4. $q$ divides $q+w[(q-1)! + 1]$ due to $1.$ and $2.$

Therefore $q+w[(q-1)! + 1]$ **is not** a prime and $a^{q+w[(q-1)! + 1]}$ **is not** in $L$.

Is my proof correct or am I missing something?